# Python Class: Singleton or Not Singleton by Passing a Value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton

I have a Python 3 class that is currently a singleton defined using a `@singleton` decorator, but occasionally it needs to **not** be a singleton.

**Question:** Is it possible to do something similar to passing a parameter when instantiating an object from the class and this parameter determines whether the class is a singleton or not a singleton?

I am trying to find an alternative to duplicating the class and making that not a singleton, but then we will have tons of duplicated code.

**`Foo.py`**

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances={}

    def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[cls]

    return getinstance

@singleton
Class Foo:
    def hello(self):
        print('hello world!')
```

**`FooNotSingleton.py`**

```
Class FooNotSingleton:
    def hello(self):
        print('hello world!')
```

**`main.py`**

```
from Foo import Foo
from FooNotSingleton import FooNotSingleton

foo = Foo()
foo.hello()

bar = FooNotSingleton()
bar.hello()
```

Comment: 1. `_singleton` is not defined. Did you mean `getinstance`?. 2. Silly question: why not just remove `@singleton` decorator?

Comment: @sanyash 1. Fixed the typo, thanks! 2. I will like to have a singleton and a non-singleton version of the same class, so the singleton version of the class should have the `@singleton` decorator, the non-singleton version should not. Maybe I am missing out something really obvious?

Comment: would you mind accepting one of given answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some extra handling in your `singleton` wrapper with a keyword trigger to bypass the non-single instantiations with `singleton=False` in your class:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances={}

    def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
        # thanks to sanyash's suggestion, using a default return instead of try/except            
        singleton = kwargs.pop('singleton', True)
        if singleton:
            if cls not in instances:
                instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
            return instances[cls]
        else:
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)

    return getinstance

@singleton
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def hello(self):
        print(f'I have value {self.val}')
```

Test:

```
s1 = Foo('single')
s2 = Foo('another single')
ns = Foo('not single', singleton=False)
s1.hello()
# I have value single
s2.hello()
# I have value single
ns.hello()
# I have value not single
```

The caveat is you'll want to reserve a keyword that aren't likely to be used to be in any of your decorated class.  The benefit is you only need to create the class once without duplication.

Comment: `singleton = kwargs.pop('singleton', True)` can replace `try: ... except` block.

Comment: Good point, wasn't aware `pop()` also has a default that won't trigger the `KeyError`.  Good to know!

Comment: a1 = Foo('apple', category='fruits')
a2 = Foo('apple', category='fruits', origin='USA')
b = Foo('grape', category='fruits')

print(a1 is a1)

print(a1 is a2)

print(a1 is b) How to pass this arguments and check comparison. If true or false.

Comment: @r.ook Need your help here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456961/python-class-singleton-pass-the-multiple-argument-to-check-comparison

Answer (score 0):

You could build the instance key based on a unique ID that you pass to the constructor. That way, the same class **and** the same ID will yield the same instance.

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances={}
    def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
        key = "{}__{}".format(cls, kwargs.get("id"))
        if key not in instances:
            instances[key] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[key]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = 0
    def hello(self):
        print('My X is:', self.x)

f1 = Foo()
f1.x = 5
f1.hello()

f2 = Foo() # same as f1
f2.hello()

f3 = Foo(id='abc') # new instance, because of new "id" parameter
f3.x = 1024
f3.hello()

f4 = Foo() # same as f1
f4.hello()
```

Output:

```
My X is: 5
My X is: 5
My X is: 1024
My X is: 5
```

Optionally: You could remove the `id` argument from kwargs before you pass it to the class constructor - and ofc you could name `id` something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue can easily be solved with inheritance. `FooNotSingleton` becomes a base class with all implementation details and `Foo` derives from it with usage of `@singleton` decorator:

**FooNotSingleton.py**

```
class FooNotSingleton:
    def hello(self):
        print('hello world!')
```

**Foo.py**

```
import FooNotSingleton

def singleton(cls):
    instances={}

    def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[cls]

    return getinstance

@singleton
class Foo(FooNotSingleton.FooNotSingleton):
    pass
```

**main.py**

```
from Foo import Foo
from FooNotSingleton import FooNotSingleton

print(id(FooNotSingleton()))
print(id(FooNotSingleton()))  # different
print(id(Foo()))
print(id(Foo()))  # same
FooNotSingleton().hello()  # both works
Foo().hello()
```